# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': X could not be cloned

Tags: javascript, function, tostring, web-worker, postmessage

I am trying to pass a function to a web worker.  I am aware of the other discussions on here, and I've found a workaround that's working for me.  I have a class that creates some webworkers, and passes options to them.  One of the options is a customizable function:

```js
  var data = {
    id: id,
    RainbowAsString: Rainbow.toString(),
    heightFunction: this.heightFunctionString(), // <-- customizable
  };

  this._workers[workerIndex].postMessage(data);
```

Now, `Rainbow` is actually a function.  What I'm doing is calling `toString()` on it, which transforms it to a string, and it can be passed to a worker without issue.  Within the worker, I intercept that, and rebuild the function:

```js
onmessage = function (e) {
  
  const {
    RainbowAsString,
    heightFunction: heightFunctionAsString,
  } = e.data;

  const rainbowCreator = new Function('return ' + RainbowAsString);
  const Rainbow = rainbowCreator();

  const heightFunctionCreator = new Function('return ' + heightFunctionAsString);
  const heightFunction = heightFunctionCreator();

  // do more stuff

}
```

This works great, for Rainbow.  However, for my `heightFunction`, its a bit more complicated.  I have a default function held in a config, but the author using my class can pass an optional replacement function to be used.  I grab that with the `heightFunctionString` method:

```js
    heightFunctionString: function () {
        if (this.options.customization?.heightFunction) {
            return this.options.customization?.heightFunction.toString();
        }

        return _config.heightFunction.toString();
    }
```

In the event that `options.customization.heightFunction` doesn't exist, we default to the `_config.heightFunction`. In that case, everything is working great.  The function is turned into a string, then transofmred back into a function in the worker.  However, for some reason, if `this.options.customization.heightFunction` exists, it does indeed get transformed into a string, but I still get an error

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': function heightFunction(R, G, B) {
        return -11111 + (R * 256 * 256 + G * 256 + B) * 0.1;
      } could not be cloned.
```

Why would this be happening in the scenario where I'm passing the function through options, rather than through config?  I've tried logging `this.heightFunctionString()` just before it gets passed to the worker for both scenarios, as well as `typeof this.heightFunctionString()`, and it is indeed a string.  What might I be missing here?

Comment: [Can't repro..](https://jsfiddle.net/r4qgwh6s/)

Comment: Kaiido! Wow thank you for taking the time.  I am not too familiar with the MessageChannel api, but even with the simpler worker api I am also [not able to reproduce this in a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-sara-3irb0).  That's my problem - I have no idea where to look to debug this.  The problem can be seen on the [function worker problem](https://github.com/slutske22/leaflet-topography/commit/c0d289294b258d5a35100c6062041bda92dbdf79) commit of my leaflet-topography plugin repo.

Comment: To reproduce, clone the repo, `npm i` and `npm run build`, cd into `example`, `npm i` and `npm start`, and once you've put in your mapbox token and the demo is available, click the second option in the layers dropdown "topotype: elevation - default".  This will fire up a bunch of workers and attempt to pass them a function as a string, as defined in the `customization` property of options that get passed to a `Topolayer`.  Obviously this is a big ask to do all that to help debug.  But short of that, I can't understand what might be causing this in my code, or even think of how to reproduce.